# Doubly Filled COMP in Contemporary English

Tags: syntax, relative-clauses

Are there any cases of doubly filled COMP in contemporary English?

Middle English had relative clauses with wh-phrases and complementisers co-occurring. I’ve also read that the variety of English spoken in Ireland can have doubly filled COMP.

I’ve found one kind of sentence that could possibly be analysed to have a doubly filled comp…

“The more (that) you read, the more (that) you learn.”

… but this could as well just be relative clauses though.

Comment: I don't think there are in standard English; but when somebody was convincing me a few years ago that "that" was not a relative pronount, but a complementiser with deleted relative pronoun, they cited some non-standard English varieties which allowed "that" with a relative pronoun.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes. Belfast English allows doubly filled COMP. You can get something like "I wonder which dish that they picked."